# Refactoring if statement to single assignment breaks Razor view when it contains a C# keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, resharper

I have a Razor view with an if statement sat within a foreach statement:

```
@{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = @"Select Item" } };
    foreach (var @case in Model.Items)
    {
        var selected = false;
        if (Model.MyProp != null && Model.MyProp.Id == @case.Id)
        {
            selected = true;
        }
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = @case.Id.ToString(), Text = @case.MyReference, Selected = selected });
    }
}
```

Resharper highlights the if statement and suggests "Replace with single assignment". Great, let's do it! We get:

```
bool selected = Model.MyProp != null && Model.MyProp.Id == @case.Id;
```

But then the project fails to build, and the following error occurs twice:

> CS1513 } expected

Once for our .cshtml file, and another time for `App_Web_44i02p0n.0.cs` (which I assume is some temporary generated file?).

If I revert the refactor then it compiles successfully.

I replaced the keyword name with something else, and that also compiles successfully.

Why does this single assignment line cause compilation errors when using a C# keyword?

Comment: I suspect it happens because of `@item`. What happens if you replace `@item` with something else that does not use `@`?

Comment: Not the keyword but the `@`. It has special meaning in Razor, so I assume it confuses rendering engine in some context. Just guesses here

Comment: @Owen Pauling, try this `bool selected = (Model.MyProp != null && Model.MyProp.Id == @case.Id); ` although this is the same thing but `CS1513 } expected` error will go away.